# How to remove username from "Me" menu (right near to power button on the top panel)?

Tags: 10.10, menu, ayatana

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I replace the MeMenu username with my actual name?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4743/how-do-i-replace-the-memenu-username-with-my-actual-name)

My user name takes approximately as long as would 6 icons. I don't need to see my username, I am the only user of my computer. How can I remove it?

I use Ubuntu 10.10.

**UPDATE:** The **answer** found:

```
gconftool -s /system/indicator/me/display --type int 0
```

**UPDATE:** Unfortunately the solution doesn't work any more. Now it totally removes the instant messaging menu (including the icon) instead of just removing a name.

Comment: This is a duplicate, so the answer belongs in the question this question is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 2):

I know no way to remove the name from the applet. Though you can remove the applet entirely, and the shutdown/logout will now be in the System menu.

Comment: Thanks! Not the answer exactly, but a very good idea still.

Comment: There is also alternate power buttons and a user switch menu applet. They might be not the look you are going for though.