# How do I replace the MeMenu username with my actual name?

Tags: indicator, menu

Whilst I like the MeMenu, one thing has always bothered me about it; rather then use my actual name, it uses my username.

So, is there anyway to change this?

Comment: There's a bug report about this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-me/+bug/604506

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To switch to your actual name enter the following in a console (Applications->Accessories->Terminal) or you can use the [gconf-editor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17249/how-do-i-use-the-gconf-editor):

```
gconftool -s /system/indicator/me/display --type int 2
```

And to switch back:

```
gconftool -s /system/indicator/me/display --type int 1
```

It is also possible to hide the name altogether and show just the icon:

```
gconftool -s /system/indicator/me/display --type int 0
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to wonder why this isn't the default...

Comment: Interestingly it is default on the original mockups. I imagine it's to save space, especially on small screens and netbooks.

Comment: Fluteflute hits the nail on its head with that last answer.

Comment: This is becoming the default in Natty.  http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/memenu-now-displays-full-user-name-in-natty/

Comment: It doesn't necessarily save space. I use likewise-open on my work computer, and domain\username is longer than my full name.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, in some cases, using the int 0 can lead to the icon disappearing altogether, so restarting gnome-panel may be necessary for the now nameless icon to reappear.

You can find the process name to kill gnome-panel via

```
ps -ef | grep panel
```