# How can i change the top right corner display Name?

Tags: user-profile, hostname

I have changed the name on `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` but the top right corner display name won't change

[image]

How can i change that name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` contains your hostname (the **computer name**). The name next to the shutdown button is your **username**.

Changing your username just to get a different name displayed is not recommended. To make your actual name to be displayed instead of your username, open a Terminal and run:

```
gconftool -s /system/indicator/me/display --type int 2
```

(taken from [fluteflute](https://askubuntu.com/q/4743/6969#4746)'s answer)

To change your actual username (which defaults to your username), go to *System* -> *Administration* -> *Users and Groups*. Select your user and click the "Change..." button after your current name. Enter whatever you like and press *OK* to save it. You'll need to re-login to make the name change take effect.

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal;

```
chfn -f "FirstName LastName" *username*
```

verify with;

```
getent passwd $USER | cut -d ':' -f 5 | cut -d ',' -f 1
```

OR

```
finger -m $USER | head -n 1 | sed 's/\(.*\)Name\:\s\(.*\)$/\2/g'
```